# How to solve $6^{2x}-10\cdot 6^x=-21$ using logarithms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

> What do I do with $\large 6^{2x}-10\cdot 6^x=-21$?

Since $6$ and $-60$ are not of the same base (nor can they be written as exponents of the same base cleanly) I am having trouble solving for $x$.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $10\cdot6^x$ instead of $60^x$ ?

Comment: I second Lucian's comment. Having it being $10\times 6^x$ is way easier than $60^x$.

Comment: 6^(2x)-10*6^x = -21 (You are so right, I inadvertently and incorrectly multiplied the two)

Comment: Then let $y=6^x$, and solve for *y*. Afterwards, select only the positive solution, since $6^x>0$ for all *x*.

Comment: Genius! Didn't even think to do that--got solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Lucian, if you put your hint/tip in answers then this question will not unanswered list.

Comment: @user132649 : You don't have $(-60)^x$; you have $-10(6^x)$.  The thing that gets raised to the power $x$ is $6$, not $60$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $6^x=y$
$$6^{2x}-10\cdot 6^x=-21$$
$$y^2-10y=-21$$
$$y^2-10y+21=0$$
Factor.
$$(y-3)(y-7)=0$$
$$y=3, \ 7$$
Replace $y$ with $6^x$
$$6^x = 3, \ 7$$
I will solve for both equations separately. Let's start with $6^x=3$
$$6^x=3$$
$$\ln(6^x)=\ln(3)$$
$$x\ln(6)=\ln(3)$$
$$x=\dfrac{\ln(3)}{\ln(6)}$$
Now for $6^x=7$
$$6^x=7$$
$$\ln(6^x)=\ln(7)$$
$$x\ln(6)=\ln(7)$$
$$x=\dfrac{\ln(7)}{\ln(6)}$$
The solutions are:
$$\displaystyle \boxed{x=\dfrac{\ln(3)}{\ln(6)}, \ \dfrac{\ln(7)}{\ln(6)}}$$